# Chrome extension disappears when Developer tools are closed

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am making a simple Chrome extension with a file upload form. It works fine when Developer tool window is open for the addon ("insepect element"), but when I try to run it without developer tools, the addon collapses when I click on the file selection button. What's wrong? I am using Chrome version 22 on OSX 10.7.5

The code is the following:

Here is the HTML part:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="upload.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="http://localhost" id="form">
      <input type="file" id="file" name="file" >
      <input type="button" id="sub" value="Upload">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here is the upload.js

```
function upload(form) {
  var formData = new FormData(form);
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.open("POST", form.getAttribute("action"));
  req.onload = function(event) {
      console.log(event.target.responseText);
  };
  req.send(formData);
}

document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    document.getElementById("sub").addEventListener("click", function() {
        upload(document.getElementById("form"));
    }, false);
 }, false );
```

And here is the manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "Issue-img",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Simple upload.",
  "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "icon.png",
      "default_popup": "upload.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
      "http://localhost/"
  ]
 }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you see some errors in logs? From the first glance, you wrote permissions for `https` scheme, but try to upload to `http`.

Comment: oh, it's a typo from minifying the real manifest to StackOverflow example :)

Comment: Does the popup close when you click the `<input type="file">` element? I cannot reproduce that on Windows Vista.

Comment: Popup based chrome extensions cant be opened if they are not in focus, when you press your File input field, a window prompt is shown and your popup is no longer in focus. when the inspect element window is open it means that you are in developer mode so they let you keep the popup open